# Recursive and flexible approach to Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: java, game, tic-tac-toe, community-challenge

## Description

This is my code for the [Weekend Challenge Reboot](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/weekend-challenge-reboot) - Tic Tac Toe Ultimate.

The game can be played here: http://www.zomis.net/ttt (along with some other variations that are also use the same code base, but with other 'controllers').

This question contains the game model and a 'controller' for the TicTacToe Ultimate game.

The classic TTT is 3*3. TTT Ultimate is a 3*3 grid of classic TTTs, so 3*3 * 3*3. As usual I wanted this code to be flexible, so technically it should be possible to extend it to a TTTUltimatePlus which would be a 3*3 grid of TTTUltimate games, or 3*3 * 3*3 * 3*3. I have not done a controller for TTTUltimatePlus yet, but the `TTBase` system would support it. When I started this project, I did not expect myself to make it work with Reversi (a.k.a. Othello), or Quantum Tic-Tac-Toe but well... when I realized how I could structure this I thought "Why not?".

My first code, having a `TTUltimateGame`, `TTBoard` and a `TTField` class had a lot of code duplication which I wanted to avoid. This made me want to make this code. The `TTBase` class is the most important one, to support any number of recursiveness (by making a TTTUltimatePlus for example) I made it as a *recursive* class. Each clickable field is a TTBase, each area containing the fields is a TTBase, and the outermost game itself is a TTBase.

#### Class Summary (695 lines in 12 files, making a total of 18218 bytes)

- HasSub.java: Interface indicating that a class contains smaller parts, 'subs' (a small field is a sub to a 3x3 area for example).
- TicFactory.java: Interface for creating TTBase objects.
- TicUtils.java: Utility methods, including code to create the Win Conditions for a TTBase.
- TTBase.java: Class that can contain more TTBases in a rectangular grid. Can be won and played by players.
- TTController.java: Abstract class for determining which TTBases that can be played and for playing at them.
- TTFactories.java: Code to instanciate variations of TTBases.
- TTMNKParameters.java: Parameters for creating a TTBase. Determines the size of the board and the number of consecutive fields that must be won by the same player.
- TTMoveListener.java: Interface for when a move has been made
- TTPlayer.java: An enum for players; X or O, and none, or both.
- TTUltimateController.java: Provides a TTController for TTT Ultimate.
- TTWinCondition.java: A rule for determining if a board is won by checking a number of fields. A classic TTT board for example has 8 win conditions: 3 rows, 3 columns and 2 diagonals.
- Winnable.java: Interface for something that can be won by a TTPlayer.

## Code

This code can also be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/Zomis/UltimateTTT)

**HasSub.java:** (15 lines, 369 bytes)

```
/**
 * Interface for classes that can contain other objects, 'subs', in a rectangular way
 *
 * @param <T> Type of sub
 */
public interface HasSub<T> extends Winnable {
    T getSub(int x, int y);
    Iterable<TTWinCondition> getWinConds();
    int getSizeX();
    int getSizeY();
    int getConsecutiveRequired();
    boolean hasSubs();
}
```

**TicFactory.java:** (5 lines, 117 bytes)

```
public interface TicFactory {
    TTBase construct(TTBase parent, int x, int y);
}
```

**TicUtils.java:** (140 lines, 4211 bytes)

```
public class TicUtils {
    /**
     * Get which board a tile will send the opponent to (in a TTTUltimate context)
     * 
     * @param tile The tile to be played
     * @return The board which the tile directs to
     */
    public static TTBase getDestinationBoard(TTBase tile) {
        TTBase parent = tile.getParent();
        if (parent == null)
            return null;
        TTBase grandpa = parent.getParent();
        if (grandpa == null)
            return null;
        return grandpa.getSub(tile.getX(), tile.getY());
    }
    /**
     * Find the win conditions which contains a specific field
     * 
     * @param field The field to look for
     * @param board Where to look for win conditions
     * @return A collection which only contains win conditions which contains the field 
     */
    public static <E extends Winnable> Collection<TTWinCondition> getWinCondsWith(E field, HasSub<E> board) {
        Collection<TTWinCondition> coll = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TTWinCondition cond : board.getWinConds()) {
            if (cond.hasWinnable(field))
                coll.add(cond);
        }
        return coll;
    }

    /**
     * Get all smaller tiles/boards in a board
     * 
     * @param board Board to scan
     * @return Collection of all smaller tiles/boards contained in board.
     */
    public static <T> Collection<T> getAllSubs(HasSub<T> board) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int sizeX = board.getSizeX();
        int sizeY = board.getSizeY();
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
                list.add(board.getSub(x, y));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively scan for smaller subs
     * 
     * @param game The outermost object to scan
     * @return A collection containing all fields within the specified 'game' which do not have any subs
     */
    public static Collection<TTBase> getAllSmallestFields(TTBase game) {
        Collection<TTBase> all = new ArrayList<>();

        for (TTBase sub : TicUtils.getAllSubs(game)) {
            if (sub.hasSubs())
                all.addAll(getAllSmallestFields(sub));
            else all.add(sub);
        }
        return all;
    }
    /**
     * Create win conditions
     * 
     * @param board The board to create win conditions for
     * @return A list of all WinConditions that was created
     */
    public static List<TTWinCondition> setupWins(final HasSub<? extends Winnable> board) {
        if (!board.hasSubs()) {
            ArrayList<TTWinCondition> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new TTWinCondition(board));
            return list;
        }

        int consecutive = board.getConsecutiveRequired();
        List<TTWinCondition> conds = new ArrayList<>();

        // Scan columns for a winner
        for (int xx = 0; xx < board.getSizeX(); xx++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, xx, 0, 0, 1));
        }

        // Scan rows for a winner
        for (int yy = 0; yy < board.getSizeY(); yy++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, 0, yy, 1, 0));
        }

        // Scan diagonals for a winner: Bottom-right
        for (int yy = 0; yy < board.getSizeY(); yy++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, 0, yy, 1, 1));
        }
        for (int xx = 1; xx < board.getSizeX(); xx++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, xx, 0, 1, 1));
        }

        // Scan diagonals for a winner: Bottom-left
        for (int xx = 0; xx < board.getSizeY(); xx++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, xx, 0, -1, 1));
        }
        for (int yy = 1; yy < board.getSizeY(); yy++) {
            newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, board.getSizeX() - 1, yy, -1, 1));
        }

        return conds;
    }

    private static void newWin(List<TTWinCondition> conds, int consecutive, List<Winnable> winnables) {
        if (winnables.size() >= consecutive) // shorter win conditions doesn't need to be added as they will never be able to win
            conds.add(new TTWinCondition(winnables, consecutive));
    }

    private static List<Winnable> loopAdd(HasSub<? extends Winnable> board,
            int xx, int yy, int dx, int dy) {
        List<Winnable> winnables = new ArrayList<>();

        Winnable tile;
        do {
            tile = board.getSub(xx, yy);
            xx += dx;
            yy += dy;
            if (tile != null)
                winnables.add(tile);
        }
        while (tile != null);

        return winnables;
    }

}
```

**TTBase.java:** (149 lines, 3623 bytes)

```
public class TTBase implements Winnable, HasSub<TTBase> {
    // Container
    private final TTBase[][] subs;
    private final TTMNKParameters mnkParams;
    private final List<TTWinCondition> winConditions;

    // Winnable
    private final TTBase parent;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private TTPlayer playedBy = TTPlayer.NONE;

    public TTBase(TTBase parent, TTMNKParameters parameters, TicFactory factory) {
        this(parent, 0, 0, parameters, factory);
    }
    public TTBase(TTBase parent, int x, int y, TTMNKParameters parameters, TicFactory factory) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.mnkParams = parameters;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.subs = new TTBase[parameters.getWidth()][parameters.getHeight()];
        for (int xx = 0; xx < parameters.getWidth(); xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < parameters.getHeight(); yy++) {
                this.subs[xx][yy] = factory.construct(this, xx, yy);
            }
        }
        this.winConditions = Collections.unmodifiableList(TicUtils.setupWins(this));
    }

    public void determineWinner() {
        TTPlayer winner = TTPlayer.NONE;
        for (TTWinCondition cond : this.winConditions) {
            winner = winner.or(cond.determineWinnerNew());
        }
        this.playedBy = winner;
    }

    @Override
    public TTBase getSub(int x, int y) {
        if (!hasSubs() && x == 0 && y == 0)
            return this;
        if (x < 0 || y < 0)
            return null;
        if (x >= getSizeX() || y >= getSizeY())
            return null;
        return subs[x][y];
    }

    @Override
    public List<TTWinCondition> getWinConds() {
        return winConditions;
    }

    @Override
    public TTPlayer getWonBy() {
        return this.playedBy;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSizeX() {
        return this.mnkParams.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSizeY() {
        return this.mnkParams.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public int getConsecutiveRequired() {
        return this.mnkParams.getConsecutiveRequired();
    }

    public TTMNKParameters getMNKParameters() {
        return this.mnkParams;
    }

    public TTBase getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean isWon() {
        return playedBy != TTPlayer.NONE;
    }

    public void setPlayedBy(TTPlayer playedBy) {
        if (playedBy == null && this.hasSubs() && parent != null)
            new Exception().printStackTrace();
        this.playedBy = playedBy;
    }

    public boolean hasSubs() {
        return getSizeX() != 0 && getSizeY() != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{Pos " + x + ", " + y + "; Size " + getSizeX() + ", " + getSizeY() + "; Played by " + getWonBy() + ". Parent is " + parent + "}";
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.setPlayedBy(TTPlayer.NONE);
        for (int xx = 0; xx < getSizeX(); xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < getSizeY(); yy++) {
                this.getSub(xx, yy).reset();
            }
        }
    }
    public int getGlobalX() {
        if (parent == null)
            return 0;
        if (parent.getParent() == null)
            return x;
        return parent.getX() * parent.getParent().getSizeX() + this.x;
    }

    public int getGlobalY() {
        if (parent == null)
            return 0;
        if (parent.getParent() == null)
            return y;
        return parent.getY() * parent.getParent().getSizeY() + this.y;
    }

    public TTBase getSmallestTile(int x, int y) {
        int subX = x / getSizeX();
        int subY = y / getSizeY();
        TTBase board = getSub(subX, subY);
        if (board == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("No such smallest tile found: " + x + ", " + y);

        return board.getSub(x - subX*getSizeX(), y - subY*getSizeY());
    }

}
```

**TTController.java:** (110 lines, 2867 bytes)

```
public abstract class TTController {

    protected final TTBase game;
    protected TTPlayer currentPlayer = TTPlayer.X;
    private TTMoveListener  moveListener;
    private StringBuilder history;

    public TTController(TTBase board) {
        this.game = board;
        this.history = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public abstract boolean isAllowedPlay(TTBase tile);

    public final boolean play(TTBase tile) {
        if (tile == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tile to play at cannot be null.");

        if (!isAllowedPlay(tile)) {
            System.out.println("Warning: Move was not made. Unable to play at " + tile);
            return false;
        }
        TTBase playedTile = tile;
        if (!this.performPlay(tile))
            return false;

        this.addToHistory(tile);

        if (this.moveListener != null)
            this.moveListener.onMove(playedTile);

        return true;
    }

    private void addToHistory(TTBase tile) {
        if (history.length() > 0)
            history.append(",");
        history.append(Integer.toString(tile.getGlobalX(), Character.MAX_RADIX));
        history.append(Integer.toString(tile.getGlobalY(), Character.MAX_RADIX));
    }

    protected abstract boolean performPlay(TTBase tile);

    public boolean play(int x, int y) {
        return this.play(game.getSmallestTile(x, y));
    }

    public TTPlayer getCurrentPlayer() {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    protected void nextPlayer() {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer.next();
    }

    public TTBase getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return game.isWon();
    }

    public TTPlayer getWonBy() {
        return game.getWonBy();
    }

    public void setOnMoveListener(TTMoveListener moveListener) {
        this.moveListener = moveListener;
    }


    public void makeMoves(String history) throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
        for (String move : history.split(",")) {
            if (move.isEmpty())
                continue;
            if (move.length() != 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexcepted move length. " + move);

            int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(move.charAt(0)), Character.MAX_RADIX);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(move.charAt(1)), Character.MAX_RADIX);

            TTBase tile = game.getSmallestTile(x, y);
            if (!this.play(tile))
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to make a move at " + x + ", " + y + ": " + tile);
        }
    }
    public String saveHistory() {
        return this.history.toString();
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.currentPlayer = TTPlayer.X;
        this.history = new StringBuilder();
        this.game.reset();
        this.onReset();
    }

    protected abstract void onReset();

    public String getViewFor(TTBase tile) {
        return tile.isWon() ? tile.getWonBy().toString() : "";
    }
}
```

**TTFactories.java:** (52 lines, 1616 bytes)

```
public class TTFactories {
    private static final TTMNKParameters mnkEmpty = new TTMNKParameters(0, 0, 0);

    private static final TicFactory lastFactory = new TicFactory() {
        @Override
        public TTBase construct(TTBase parent, int x, int y) {
            return new TTBase(parent, x, y, mnkEmpty, null);
        }
    };
    private static final TicFactory areaFactory = new TicFactory() {
        @Override
        public TTBase construct(TTBase parent, int x, int y) {
            return new TTBase(parent, x, y, parent.getMNKParameters(), lastFactory);
        }
    };

    public static class Factory implements TicFactory {
        private final TTMNKParameters   mnk;
        private final TicFactory    next;
        public Factory(TTMNKParameters mnk, TicFactory nextFactory) {
            this.mnk = mnk;
            this.next = nextFactory;
        }
        @Override
        public TTBase construct(TTBase parent, int x, int y) {
            return new TTBase(parent, x, y, mnk, next);
        }
    }

    public TTBase classicMNK(int width, int height, int consecutive) {
        return new TTBase(null, new TTMNKParameters(width, height, consecutive), lastFactory);
    }
    public TTBase classicMNK(int mnk) {
        return classicMNK(mnk, mnk, mnk);
    }
    public TTBase ultimate(int mnk) {
        return ultimate(mnk, mnk, mnk);
    }
    public TTBase ultimate(int width, int height, int consecutive) {
        return new TTBase(null, new TTMNKParameters(width, height, consecutive), areaFactory);
    }
    public TTBase ultimate() {
        return ultimate(3);
    }
    public TTBase othello(int size) {
        return new TTBase(null, new TTMNKParameters(size, size, size + 1), lastFactory);
    }


}
```

**TTMNKParameters.java:** (27 lines, 533 bytes)

```
public class TTMNKParameters {

    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final int consecutiveRequired;

    public TTMNKParameters(int width, int height, int consecutiveRequired) {
         this.width = width;
         this.height = height;
         this.consecutiveRequired = consecutiveRequired;
    }

    public int getConsecutiveRequired() {
        return consecutiveRequired;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

}
```

**TTMoveListener.java:** (5 lines, 104 bytes)

```
public interface TTMoveListener {
    void onMove(TTBase playedAt);
}
```

**TTPlayer.java:** (54 lines, 1273 bytes)

```
public enum TTPlayer {

    NONE, X, O, XO;

    public TTPlayer next() {
        if (!isExactlyOnePlayer())
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only possible to call .next() on a real player but it was called on " + this);
        return this == X ? O : X;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if this player is (also) another player.<br>
     * This is the same as <code>this.and(other) == other</code>
     * 
     * @param other
     * @return
     */
    public boolean is(TTPlayer other) {
        return this.and(other) == other;
    }

    public TTPlayer and(TTPlayer other) {
        if (this == NONE || other == NONE || other == null)
            return NONE;
        if (isExactlyOnePlayer() && other.isExactlyOnePlayer())
            return this == other ? this : NONE;
        if (this == XO)
            return other;
        return other.and(this);
    }

    public boolean isExactlyOnePlayer() {
        return this == X || this == O;
    }

    public static boolean isExactlyOnePlayer(TTPlayer winner) {
        return winner != null && winner.isExactlyOnePlayer();
    }

    public TTPlayer or(TTPlayer other) {
        if (this == NONE || other == null)
            return other;
        if (other == NONE)
            return this;
        if (this == XO)
            return this;
        if (this != other)
            return XO;
        return this;
    }

}
```

**TTUltimateController.java:** (53 lines, 1386 bytes)

```
public class TTUltimateController extends TTController {
    // TODO: Try making it even more Ultimate by adding one more dimension, and use Map<TTBase, TTBase> activeBoards. Just for fun.
    private TTBase activeBoard = null;

    public TTUltimateController(TTBase board) {
        super(board);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowedPlay(TTBase tile) {
        TTBase area = tile.getParent();
        if (area == null)
            return false;
        TTBase game = tile.getParent().getParent();

        if (!tile.getWonBy().equals(TTPlayer.NONE))
            return false;
        if (area.getWonBy().isExactlyOnePlayer())
            return false;
        if (game.isWon())
            return false;

        return activeBoard == null || activeBoard == area || activeBoard.getWonBy() != TTPlayer.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performPlay(TTBase tile) {
        tile.setPlayedBy(currentPlayer);
        activeBoard = TicUtils.getDestinationBoard(tile);
        nextPlayer();

        // Check for win condition on tile and if there is a win, cascade to it's parents
        do {
            tile.determineWinner();
            tile = tile.isWon() ? tile.getParent() : null;
        }
        while (tile != null);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        this.activeBoard = null;
    }

}
```

**TTWinCondition.java:** (78 lines, 2026 bytes)

```
public class TTWinCondition implements Iterable<Winnable> {

    private final List<Winnable> winnables;
    private final int consecutive;

    public TTWinCondition(Winnable... winnables) {
        this(Arrays.asList(winnables));
    }

    public TTWinCondition(List<? extends Winnable> winnables) {
        this(winnables, winnables.size());
    }

    public TTWinCondition(List<? extends Winnable> winnables, int consecutive) {
        if (winnables.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't have an empty win condition!");
        this.winnables = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Winnable>(winnables));
        this.consecutive = consecutive;
    }

    public int neededForWin(TTPlayer player) {
        return winnables.size() - hasCurrently(player);
    }
    public boolean isWinnable(TTPlayer byPlayer) {
        return hasCurrently(byPlayer.next()) == 0;
    }
    public int hasCurrently(TTPlayer player) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Winnable winnable : winnables) {
            if (winnable.getWonBy().and(player) == player)
                i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public TTPlayer determineWinnerNew() {
        TTPlayer winner = TTPlayer.NONE;

        int[] consecutivePlayers = new int[TTPlayer.values().length];
        for (Winnable winnable : winnables) {
            TTPlayer current = winnable.getWonBy();
            for (TTPlayer pl : TTPlayer.values()) {
                int i = pl.ordinal();
                if (pl.and(current) == pl) {
                    consecutivePlayers[i]++;
                }
                else consecutivePlayers[i] = 0;

                if (consecutivePlayers[i] >= this.consecutive) {
                    winner = winner.or(pl);
                }
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }

    public boolean hasWinnable(Winnable field) {
        return winnables.contains(field);
    }

    public int size() {
        return winnables.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Winnable> iterator() {
        return new ArrayList<Winnable>(this.winnables).iterator();
    }

}
```

**Winnable.java:** (7 lines, 93 bytes)

```
public interface Winnable {

    TTPlayer getWonBy();

}
```

## Usage / Test

You can play the game on http://www.zomis.net/ttt . The GUI checks with the controller if a field can be played or not and uses the methods provided by the controller to make a move on a field. The GUI is written using GWT (Google Web Toolkit) which compiles my Java code to JavaScript and obfuscates it for me.

## Questions

Things I am quite proud of includes the `TTWinCondition` class, especially the way TTWinConditions is created.

I am also quite proud of the `TTPlayer` enum and how it includes both NONE and XO (both), and it's `and` and `or` methods.

Things I am not so proud of includes the `TTBase` class. It is the best thing I could come up with though (and it is probably the most unique way of all the challenge implementations). I really couldn't come up with a more flexible way that would support any number of recursiveness, and at the same time removing code duplication.

This project uses Java 7. It also needs to support GWT so I cannot use `String.format`.

I'd mostly like comments about how I have designed these classes and interfaces. And if anyone knows a better way to do things than what I have done here, I'd love to hear them.

You may not agree with my naming of classes to start with `TT`, but I do this to make it easier for me to find my TTT-specific classes when using Eclipse's Ctrl + Shift + T keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not much to criticize in your code.... and there is a lot of code to go though.

Mostly really neat, and, it takes a while to 'grok' it, but it comes together OK.

Here's a laundry-list of small items (there are no big Items I can see):

- In TTUtils:

  - `getWinCondsWith` is a method that is never called from anywhere
  - `getAllSmallestFields` should be called `getAllSmallestSubs` to match other methods.
- In TTBase:

  - Unmodifiable in constructor:

    > ```
    > this.winConditions = Collections.unmodifiableList(TicUtils.setupWins(this));
    > ```

    I would expect the unmodifiable constraint to be set in `setupWins()`, in other words it should return an unmodifyable list rather than having that imposed outside the call.
  - in `setPlayedBy()` you have:

    > ```
    > if (playedBy == null && this.hasSubs() && parent != null)
    >      new Exception().printStackTrace();
    > ```

    No Braces is against Java code-style

    You are printing a stack trace, but continuing to set the value `null` anyway.

    This would be a good location for an `assert`.
- TTFactories

  - all the private-static-final fields should be ALL_UPPERCASE per the [Java Guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)
- TTPlayer

  - [un-braced 1-liner if statements again](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395):
  - or - if `this==NONE` and `other == null`, then why return null instead of NONE?

    > ```
    >     public TTPlayer or(TTPlayer other) {
    >         if (this == NONE || other == null)
    >             return other;
    >         if (other == NONE)
    >             return this;
    >         if (this == XO)
    >             return this;
    >         if (this != other)
    >             return XO;
    >         return this;
    >     }
    > ```

Answer (score 5):

*More than four years later...* I discovered a bug in the code below:

```
// Scan diagonals for a winner: Bottom-left
for (int xx = 0; xx < board.getSizeY(); xx++) {
    newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, xx, 0, -1, 1));
}
for (int yy = 1; yy < board.getSizeY(); yy++) {
    newWin(conds, consecutive, loopAdd(board, board.getSizeX() - 1, yy, -1, 1));
}
```

When you mix `x` and `y` on the same line, it's usually an indication that you are doing something wrong. Your code can be used in any [MNK-game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game) which is nice, but this code will not check for a winning condition in this case for a 7,6,4 game (Connect Four):

```
0000000
0000000
0000X00
000XO00
00XOO00
0XOOX00
```

Because the last bottom-left scan is missing because of `getSizeY()` being one less than `getSizeX()`, correct would be:

```
for (int xx = 0; xx < board.getSizeX(); xx++) {
```

(Seems like [I have a thing for finding bugs four years later](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179676/31562))

Answer (score 2):

*Almost six years later...* I discovered a bug in the code below:

```
@Override
public boolean isAllowedPlay(TTBase tile) {
    TTBase area = tile.getParent();
    if (area == null)
        return false;
    TTBase game = tile.getParent().getParent();

    if (!tile.getWonBy().equals(TTPlayer.NONE))
        return false;
    if (area.getWonBy().isExactlyOnePlayer())
        return false;
    if (game.isWon())
        return false;

    return activeBoard == null || activeBoard == area || activeBoard.getWonBy() != TTPlayer.NONE;
}
```

Now let's say that we have this map:

```
__O __X XOX
_O_ _OO XOX
O_X X_O OXO

__O X_O O_X
X_O OX_ O_X
O_O OXX OXO

X_X O__ ___
X_X XOO XXX
XXO OXO OXX
```

Looking at the "bigger picture" the areas won are

```
O__
OXO
XOX
```

Say that the last move was the 'X' in "__X" on the first row. This leads to the `activeBoard` being the area in the top right. This area is not won by anyone, but the whole area is full. So it should somehow be considered as a draw. The statement `activeBoard.getWonBy() != TTPlayer.NONE` will return false in this case, which leads to no current tile is allowed to play at. The game is stuck.

The solution: Support draws.